# Master's degree in game design

Tags: masters, design

Would it be recommended to join a game design master's course after an undergraduate degree in Computer Science? What would give one a better base for pursuing a Master's Degree in game/graphic design?

Comment: Game design is NOT computer science.

Comment: I know that, however I cannot change that now. I'm just asking what my options are if I really want to pursue game design.

Comment: @ResearchEnthusiast, citation needed.

Comment: @ResearchEnthusiast: I know several CS theorists and even Logicians who would say otherwise, as they spend their time doing game design. Question is, what exactly about the game is being designed.

Comment: It's been three years and I now realize this was a really silly question. The idea was that I was trying to explore the field and to answer the question, there is no "recommendation" - it's just a personal preference. If anyone following this wants to learn more about game design, I'd suggest you start 3D Modeling, animation, and try creating a basic game (Unity3D offers some interesting mini-game tutorials that I did try). It's unrelated, but I did decide to move on, pursuing "CS and not Game Design" as per ResearchEnthusiast above. I appreciate the help in any case. Cheers!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> Would it be recommended to join a game design master's course after an
>   undergraduate degree in Computer Science?

If that is what you are interested in, go for it

> What would give one a better base for pursuing a Master's Degree in
>   game/graphic design?

Self-learning. Look at code on GitHub, and try to learn from it, improve their designs. Something to start with, https://github.com/showcases/web-games